# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREGIGN KEY constraint

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am a green asp.net developer and I am using the latest entity framework with my project. I am having an issue seeding my database with autogenerated values(I think). Here is the exact error.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
public class Address
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
// some more properties
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
        [ForeignKey("Address")]        
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

// some more properties
}

public class Shelter
{
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Address")]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
// some more properties
}
//seed
private void CreateShelters()
{
    EntityEntry<Address> MspcaAddress = DbContext.Addresses.Add(new Address()
    {
                Street = "350 S Huntington Ave",
                City = "Jamaica Plain",
                State = "MA",
                AreaCode = "02130",
                Latitude = 42.3228928,
                Longititude = -71.11120540000002
    });
     EntityEntry<Address> BostonAnimalCareAndControlAddress = DbContext.Addresses.Add(new Address()
     {
                Street = "26 Mahler Rd",
                City = "Roslindale",
                State = "MA",
                AreaCode = "02131",
                Latitude = 42.2943377,
                Longititude = -71.12153390000003
            });
            EntityEntry<Address> AnimalRescueLeagueOfBostonAddress = DbContext.Addresses.Add(new Address()
            {
                Street = "10 Chandler St",
                City = "Boston",
                State = "MA",
                AreaCode = "0S2116",
                Latitude = 42.3470486,
                Longititude = -71.06976929999996
            });

            EntityEntry<Shelter> Mspca = DbContext.Shelters.Add(new Shelter()
            {
                Name = "MCSPA",
                AddressId = MspcaAddress.Entity.AddressId
            });
            EntityEntry<Shelter> BostonAnimalCareAndControl = DbContext.Shelters.Add(new Shelter()
            {
                Name = "Boston Animal Care And Control",
                AddressId = BostonAnimalCareAndControlAddress.Entity.AddressId
            });
            EntityEntry<Shelter> AnimalRescueLeagueOfBoston = DbContext.Shelters.Add(new Shelter()
            {
                Name = "Animal Rescue League Of Boston Address",
                AddressId = AnimalRescueLeagueOfBostonAddress.Entity.AddressId
            });
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
```

I tried recreating the database to see if was an issue with inconsistent data/tables but I am still getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Putting a bounty does not make the question better. You still need to provide [mcve] in order to avoid follow up comments like *I'm still getting error ...*. Because the exception message clearly indicates the problem is not in the code provided (although most likely it has the same issue), but in a code inserting `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: The code you provided does not add new `ApplicationUser` to the database at all while the error says that foreign key is violated for `ApplicationUser`. Are you sure you are debugging and sharing the same code. Please re-look at the posted code post the correct code if it's not the same.

Answer (score 4):

Your "`Shelter`"  entities, which you are trying to seed, require that you submit an existing `AddressID` Your code above tries to Get The AddressId of an address that has not been created yet.

You must first Commit your addresses to the database (using   `DbContext.SaveChanges();`)

Then, you can create the Shelter entities with the retrieved AddressId. The code below shows a sample of how you can do this, but you may have to re-write the queries that fetch the addressId. Or, you may have to separate them from the insert process altogether.

```
    private void CreateShelters()
{
    EntityEntry<Address> MspcaAddress = DbContext.Addresses.Add(new Address()
    {
                Street = "350 S Huntington Ave",
                City = "Jamaica Plain",
                State = "MA",
                AreaCode = "02130",
                Latitude = 42.3228928,
                Longititude = -71.11120540000002
    });
     EntityEntry<Address> BostonAnimalCareAndControlAddress = DbContext.Addresses.Add(new Address()
     {
                Street = "26 Mahler Rd",
                City = "Roslindale",
                State = "MA",
                AreaCode = "02131",
                Latitude = 42.2943377,
                Longititude = -71.12153390000003
            });
            EntityEntry<Address> AnimalRescueLeagueOfBostonAddress = DbContext.Addresses.Add(new Address()
            {
                Street = "10 Chandler St",
                City = "Boston",
                State = "MA",
                AreaCode = "0S2116",
                Latitude = 42.3470486,
                Longititude = -71.06976929999996
            });

    DbContext.SaveChanges();


            EntityEntry<Shelter> Mspca = DbContext.Shelters.Add(new Shelter()
            {
                Name = "MCSPA",
                AddressId = MspcaAddress.Entity.AddressId
            });
            EntityEntry<Shelter> BostonAnimalCareAndControl = DbContext.Shelters.Add(new Shelter()
            {
                Name = "Boston Animal Care And Control",
                AddressId = DbContext.Addresses.Where(x => x.Street == "26 Mahler Rd").FirstOrDefault().AddressId
       });
            EntityEntry<Shelter> AnimalRescueLeagueOfBoston = DbContext.Shelters.Add(new Shelter()
            {
                Name = "Animal Rescue League Of Boston Address",
                AddressId = DbContext.Addresses.Where(x => x.Street == "10 Chandler St").FirstOrDefault().AddressId

            });
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Hope this is enough for you to go by. If the queries for the addressId don't work let me know and I will be happy to help you out with those.

Comment: Separated the operations as mentioned but I am getting the same error. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ApplicationUser_Address_AddressId". The conflict occurred in database "WalkFred-12340be6-0442-4622-b782-a7412bb7d321", table "dbo.Address", column 'AddressId'.`

Comment: I have edited the code with a sample of how to retrieve a valid AddressId. you can tinker with that to get the correct Addressid

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into my project and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I just fixed one the queries which had an extra space in there. But like I said you will need to tinker with the queries that return the AddressId. Start by putting breakpoints where those queries are so that you can see whether you are getting a real addressId value if you don't you will need to take those queries out of the insert new statement and retrieve the address value separately.

Comment: Please let me know if you were able to get the AddressId. And if my recommendations were helpful. If you are still not getting the AddressId. then try extracting in a separate query. Let me know if you need any help with that.

Answer (score 2):

The key :) to this issue is to use reference properties instead of Id values. This means: set `Address` instead of `AddressId`. When EF saves the changes, it will figure out the dependencies between the entities and save them all in the right order, while setting the generated `AddressId` key values just in time as foreign key values.

The essence of you code (i.e. leaving out the property assignments, for brevity) should look like this:

```
var mspcaAddress = new Address();
var bostonAnimalCareAndControlAddress = new Address();
var animalRescueLeagueOfBostonAddress = new Address();
context.Addresses.AddRange(new[]
{
    mspcaAddress,
    bostonAnimalCareAndControlAddress,
    animalRescueLeagueOfBostonAddress
});

var mspca = new Shelter()
{
    Address = mspcaAddress
};
var bostonAnimalCareAndControl = new Shelter()
{
    Address = bostonAnimalCareAndControlAddress
};
var animalRescueLeagueOfBoston = new Shelter()
{
    Address = animalRescueLeagueOfBostonAddress
};
context.Shelters.AddRange(new[]
{
    mspca,
    bostonAnimalCareAndControl,
    animalRescueLeagueOfBoston
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Although the error you show applies to an `AddressId` in `ApplicationUser`, I think a similar approach in creating `ApplicationUser`s will solve the issue.

By the way, you can do without the first `context.Addresses.AddRange` statement. The addresses will be added by adding the shelters.

Note that I also removed the `EntityEntry`s from the code. I think they needlessly complicate the code. You only need the simple objects you're creating.

Comment: Just for the record, I did not down vote your answer. I actually noticed it yesterday and I like it! (assuming if it works, which I haven't tested).  BTW,You also don't show how to seed the address fields. Not a big deal but some of those may be required (not null).